# retrieving a serialized Playerprefs specific value in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to retrieve my integer value in my `SaveState` class which is already serialized as a string in `Playerprefs` and I want to access its values on my `PlayerHealth` and store it on a float variable. I'm just new in c# thanks for understanding I hope someone can help me in this.

This is my `SaveState` class:

```
public class SaveState  {
    public float FullHealth = 10; //The value that i Want
    public float staminaPTS;
}
```

This is my `PlayerHealth` class:

```
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour {
    public SaveState stateREF;
    float bulan_fullhp;
    float bulan_fullsp;
    float currHP;
    float currSP;

    //HUD Variables
    public Slider healthSlider;

    void Start () {
        load ();
        bulan_fullhp = // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO REFERENCE THE SERIALIZED PLAYERPREF "FUllHealth" VALUE IN MY Save_State Class
        currHP = bulan_fullhp;
        currSP = bulan_fullsp;

        //Hud Iniitialization
        healthSlider.maxValue = bulan_fullhp;
        healthSlider.value = bulan_fullhp; 
        Debug.Log (currHP);
    }

    public void save() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("save", Helper.Serialize <SaveState> (stateREF));
    }

    public void load() {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("save")) {
            stateREF = Helper.Deserialize<SaveState> (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("save"));
        } else {

            stateREF = new SaveState ();
            save ();
        }
    }

    public void addDamage(float damage) {
        if (damage <= 0)
            return;
        currHP -= damage;
        healthSlider.value = currHP;
        if (currHP <= 0) {
            makeDead ();
        }
    }

    void makeDead() {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is my `Serialization` class:

```
public static class Helper  {

    //Serialze
    public static string Serialize <T> (this T toSerialize) {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer (typeof(T));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter ();
        xml.Serialize (writer, toSerialize);
        return writer.ToString ();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T> (this string toDeserialze) {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer (typeof(T));
        StringReader reader = new StringReader (toDeserialze);
        return (T)xml.Deserialize (reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention `int` in the question body, but the code contains `floats`. Which is it?

Comment: sorry for that, its a float , I already edited it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You going with XML and the process will be similar but I will answer with JSON.

First you have your SaveState as Serializable

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveState  
{
   public float FullHealth = 10; //The value that i Want
   public float staminaPTS;
}
```

At that point you can turn that into JSON with JsonUtility:

```
SaveState ss = new SaveState();
ss.FullHealth = 10f;
ss.staminaPTS = 20f;
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(ss);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Save", json);
```

next you want to retrieve:

```
string json = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Save", null);
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) == true) { return; } // no saving
SaveState ss = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveState>(json);
Debug.Log($"{ss.FullHealth} {ss.staminaPTS}");
```

simple and does not require external libraries as JsonUtility is part of UnityEngine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding your question, but will

```
bulan_fullhp = stateRef.FullHealth;
```

not do exactly what you want in this case?

Comment: So basically I want to pass the FullHealth value to my float value in "bulan_fullhp". It just  say NullReferenceException Object Reference not set to an Object when I write that code sir.